# How to determine the bounds of plot area of a JavaFX XYChart

Tags: java, javafx

I want to get the bounds (i.e. `Bounds`) of the `XYChart` plot area, which I define as the area contained within the axes of the plot (i.e. the axes form two legs of a rectangle).   The ultimate purpose is to constrain a rubber band rectangle on the plot area.  I started with [this example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/7252698) and added in the constraint.

Based on the comments from James_D and kleopatra, I created a [MVCE](https://gist.github.com/zzmgck/6aab84b439e019dd668cc401a48693dd).  I think the MVCE works remarkably well and compiles without warnings. More importantly, kleopatra's comment led to finding the bug when using the [chart-plot-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588118/how-to-determine-pixel-position-of-line-chart-origin) method.  The MVCE implements both methods.  The chart-plot-background works for both ValueAxis and CategoryAxis.  The axis method currently only works for ValueAxis.

Is using the bounds of `.chart-plot-background` a reliable method for determining the plot area or is using the value bounds of each axis more reliable?  The axis approach definitely has more steps and more code.

## Other options

I looked at the JavaFX source and `plotArea` looked promising but it isn't accessible.

The `plotContent` member is accessible via `lookup(".plot-content")` but groups all the data points, some of which may be outside the range set in the axes. Thus, the bounds of `plotContent` can be larger than the plot area bounds.

Comment: I'd recommend the axis approach. *"I would prefer to avoid storing the two axes as members in the class"* Can you explain why?

Comment: @James_D. It's an old habit from memory constrained days of yore (plus I grew up on DDJ and the slogan "Running Light Without Overbyte" has stuck in mind). The habit has served me well dealing with large datasets, so I try to be lightweight. In this case, I'm guess it would just be a reference and not a clone.

Comment: [mcve] please <g> .. and one problem per question (otherwise it's hard to answer concisely)

Comment: why do you use the (grand)parent (chart) for toScene coordinate transformation of the plotBackground? btw: scenicview is a nice tool for getting a visual idea of the scenegraph.

Comment: Thank you @kleopatra!  Your comment helped me find the bug, which I fixed in the MVCE.  I've rephrased the question to focus on which method is more reliable.